# How to use Group query in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to use `Group` in MongoDB. I have no idea what is `group` so I don't know how to use it.

My modal is like below.

```
const historySchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: String, required: true },
    customerId: {type: String, required: true}
  },
);
```

In here, `customerId` is user's `id` and `city` is user visited city.
And I want to find total `price` of specific `city`.
Like below.

```
{
   City A: 1000
   City B: 2000
   City C: 3000
}
```

Comment: You can use the aggregation `$group` stage to perform grouping on the documents. You need to know on what field you want to group on and also what data you want to accumulate data by the grouped field. Grouping is generally used for accumulating data - like sum, average or just collect data of the group in an array, etc. You can also group by all the documents in the collection - for example, get the count of the documents.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. Could you please answer this question, not comment?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem like below.

```
const fetchedData = await History.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
      _id: "$city",
      totalPrice: {
        "$sum": {
          "$round": [
            "$price"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
 ]
)
```

Then get the max price value in `fetchedData`.

Maybe there will be more smarter way.